# Pagination with spring boot usiing jpa

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How can I implement a method that return a page of objects using JpaRepository and not PagingAndSortingRepository ?

My repository

```
public interface GroupRepository extends JpaRepository<Group, Long> {   
    @Query(value = "SELECT g FROM Group")
    Page<Group> listAllByPage(Pageable pageable);
}
```

My service implementation:

```
@Override
public 
Page<Group> findGroupesByPagination(Pageable pageable) {
    return groupeRepository.listAllByPage(pageable);
}
```

My rest Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/groups", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Page<Group> list( Pageable pageable){
    Page<Group> groupes = groupeServiceImpl.findGroupesByPagination(pageable);
    return groupes;
}
```

Finally I got this error:

> Error creating bean with name 'groupServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'groupeRepository'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'groupRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Validation failed for query for method public abstract
>   org.springframework.data.domain.Page
>   rimtrack.org.repository.GroupRepository.listAllByPage(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)!

Comment: Try to add 'g' after 'Group' in select query: "select g from Group g"

Comment: yes thanks  this is the right answer

Comment: Don't forget to +1 my comment ;)

Comment: yes i would like but how to do it  ???

Comment: Click on the up-arrow on the left of my comment ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The query can be defined by an annotation somewhere or declared by other means. Consult the documentation of the specific store to find available options for that store. If the repository infrastructure does not find a declared query for the method at bootstrap time, it fails.

You should using Spring Data Jpa method.   [Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts)

```
  Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

Please change repository class.

Exam:

```
public interface GroupRepository extends JpaRepository<Group, Long> {   
  Page<Group> findAlll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response but  i got the same error what should i do please help

Comment: Please write full stack trace.

Comment: what does you mean by full stack trace. #jackk??

Comment: Console Error messages.

Comment: Did you changed GroupRepository class.

Comment: i cant print it is too long

Comment: Is This error :Page rimtrack.org.repository.GroupRepository.listAllByPage(org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)!

Comment: no this time is by  rimtrack.org.repository.GroupRepository.listAlll(org.sp‌​ringframework.data.d‌​omain.Pageable)!

Comment: Not listAlll . You must write findAll.

Comment: yes thanks a lot , but the probleme is "select g from #{#entityName} g" i forgot to add g